# How do I properly extract information from this xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to query an xml document to print out higher level element attributes that are associated to lower level elements. I getting results that not consist with the xml structure.  Basically this is the code that I have so far.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('movies2.xml') root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib) print()

mov = root.findall("./genre/decade/movie/[year='2000']")
for movie in mov:
    print(child.attrib['category'], movie.attrib['title'])
```

Which yields this-

```
genre {'category': 'Action'}
genre {'category': 'Thriller'}
genre {'category': 'Comedy'}

Comedy X-Men
Comedy American Psycho
```

The last two lines should really be listing two different genre attributes associated with the movie titles if one examines the xml-

```
Action X-Men
Thriller American Psycho
```

This is the xml for reference-

> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
> <collection>
>     <genre category="Action">
>         <decade years="1980s">
>             <movie favorite="True" title="Indiana Jones: The raiders of 
>               the lost Ark">
>                 <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
>                 <year>1981</year>
>                 <rating>PG</rating>
>                 <description>
>                 'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones 
>                 is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the 
>                 Covenant before the Nazis.'
>                 </description>
>             </movie>
>                <movie favorite="True" title="THE KARATE KID">
>                <format multiple="Yes">DVD,Online</format>
>                <year>1984</year>
>                <rating>PG</rating>
>                <description>None provided.</description>
>             </movie>
>             <movie favorite="False" title="Back 2 the Future">
>                <format multiple="False">Blu-ray</format>
>                <year>1985</year>
>                <rating>PG</rating>
>                <description>Marty McFly</description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>
>         <decade years="1990s">
>             <movie favorite="False" title="X-Men">
>                <format multiple="Yes">dvd, digital</format>
>                <year>2000</year>
>                <rating>PG-13</rating>
>                <description>Two mutants come to a private academy for     >                     their kind whose resident superhero team must 
>                 oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers. 
>                </description>
>             </movie>
>             <movie favorite="True" title="Batman Returns">
>                <format multiple="No">VHS</format>
>                <year>1992</year>
>                <rating>PG13</rating>
>                <description>NA.</description>
>             </movie>
>                <movie favorite="False" title="Reservoir Dogs">
>                <format multiple="No">Online</format>
>                <year>1992</year>
>                <rating>R</rating>
>                <description>WhAtEvER I Want!!!?!</description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>    
>     </genre>
>
>     <genre category="Thriller">
>         <decade years="1970s">
>             <movie favorite="False" title="ALIEN">
>                 <format multiple="Yes">DVD</format>
>                 <year>1979</year>
>                 <rating>R</rating>
>                 <description>"""""""""</description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>
>         <decade years="1980s">
>             <movie favorite="True" title="Ferris Bueller's Day Off">
>                 <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
>                 <year>1986</year>
>                 <rating>PG13</rating>
>                 <description>Funny movie about a funny guy</description>
>             </movie>
>             <movie favorite="FALSE" title="American Psycho">
>                 <format multiple="No">blue-ray</format>
>                 <year>2000</year>
>                 <rating>Unrated</rating>
>                 <description>psychopathic Bateman</description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>
>     </genre>
>
>     <genre category="Comedy">
>         <decade years="1960s">
>             <movie favorite="False" title="Batman: The Movie">
>                 <format multiple="Yes">DVD,VHS</format>
>                 <year>1966</year>
>                 <rating>PG</rating>
>                 <description>What a joke!</description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>
>         <decade years="2010s">
>             <movie favorite="True" title="Easy A">
>                 <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
>                 <year>2010</year>
>                 <rating>PG--13</rating>
>                 <description>Emma Stone = Hester Prynne</description>
>             </movie>
>             <movie favorite="True" title="Dinner for SCHMUCKS">
>                 <format multiple="Yes">DVD,digital,Netflix</format>
>                 <year>2011</year>
>                 <rating>Unrated</rating>
>                 <description>Tim (Rudd) is a rising executive who 
>                  'succeeds' in finding the perfect guest, IRS employee 
>                  Barry (Carell), for his boss' monthly event, a so-called 
>                  'dinner for idiots,' which offers certain advantages to 
>                  the exec who shows up with the biggest buffoon.
>                 </description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>
>         <decade years="1980s">
>             <movie favorite="False" title="Ghostbusters">
>                 <format multiple="No">Online,VHS</format>
>                 <year>1984</year>
>                 <rating>PG</rating>
>                 <description>Who ya gonna call?</description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>
>         <decade years="1990s">
>             <movie favorite="True" title="Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves">
>                 <format multiple="No">Blu_Ray</format>
>                 <year>1991</year>
>                 <rating>Unknown</rating>
>                 <description>Robin Hood slaying</description>
>             </movie>
>         </decade>
>     </genre>
> </collection>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial loop:

```
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib) print()
```

leaves `child` set to the last child; and so `child.attrib['category']` will always be the last child's category. In your case, the last child was a comedy. For every movie in your second loop:

```
for movie in mov:
   print(child.attrib['category'], movie.attrib['title'])
```

You're printing the category for the last child found in the first loop; so they all print "Comedy".

Edit: this will at least select the same movies with the correct genre tag, but may have different ordering:

```
for child in root:
    mov = child.findall("./decade/movie/[year='2000']")
    for movie in mov:
        print(child.attrib['category'], movie.attrib['title'])
```

Another approach, using [lxml](https://lxml.de/) instead of elementree:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('movies2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

mov = root.findall("./genre/decade/movie/[year='2000']")
for movie in mov:
    print(movie.getparent().getparent().attrib['category'], movie.attrib['title'])
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  How might I build a 'thread' that connects the genre attribute to the movie title?  There must be something I am missing in the query.

Comment: I don't think elementtree can reach back up to a parent or grandparent, so you'll have some trouble with that approach.

You can approach it slightly differently, iterating first all the genres, then basing your findall off of the genres. But they may come out in a different order, grouped by genre. I'll edit the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Also, I just checked, and lxml (https://lxml.de/) does have that reach-back capability, but lxml is not built-in, you'd need to install it. I ordinarily use lxml, because I do XSLT, which lxml supports, but elementtree does not.

I'll add another example using lxml.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Looks good. Traveling at the moment, so I will have to try it when I’m back.  The lxml approach looks particularly more intuitive - and I have it installed so we’ll see.